# Pyglet window=pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True) error

Tags: python, window, importerror, pyglet

Running python 2.7.8 on OSX 10.9

I have installed and imported pyglet, but when I run

```
window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)
```

It returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 306, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1669, in <module>
    from pyglet.window.carbon import CarbonPlatform, CarbonWindow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/carbon/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pyglet.window import key
ImportError: cannot import name key
```

What would explain such an error? I have made sure that everything is running 32 bit, and checked compatibility.

Edit: full code:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    pyglet.gl.glColor4f(1.0,0,0,1.0)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES,
        ('v2i', (10, 15, 30, 35))
    )

pyglet.app.run()
```

I fixed the previous error, I had a misnamed file... whoops...

but now I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jackwoodrow/Desktop/TOK", line 3, in <module>
    window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 306, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1669, in <module>
    from pyglet.window.carbon import CarbonPlatform, CarbonWindow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/carbon/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    framework='/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 90, in load_library
    return self.load_framework(kwargs['framework'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 226, in load_framework
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(realpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: Can you locate the file `key` that python is attempting to import?

Comment: Yes,line 49 of the file is "from pyglet.window import key"

Comment: hi, could you please post all of the code?

Comment: added full code, and some other detail

Comment: You might find some help here : [http://twistedpairdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-pyglet-in-mac-os-x/]